# Add an element at the end of a LinkedList<T>

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a code which add a node at the end of a LinkedList but I don't understand how it works: when the code ends else statement the top node has the previous elements and add the pointer elements at the final of the list.

I don't know when the pointer elements are added at top node. Why does this happen and how does it works?

```
//Link element as latest of the List
public void addAtTheEnd(T element) {
    Node<T> aux = new Node<>(element);
    
    if(this.isEmpty()) {
        top = aux;
    } else {
        Node<T> pointer = top;            
        while (pointer.getNext() != null) {
            pointer = pointer.getNext();
        }
        pointer.setNext(aux);
    }
    size++;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi, basically, you are traversing through the end of the list's node every time you want to add. Did you get that idea?

Comment: @BatuhanTosyalı yes, to add at the final of the list, but i don´t understand when the pointer node is added to the top node, this happen when the code ends else statement

Comment: @p32094 when does the aux node reference to the top node?

Comment: @AgustínSamper did any of answer help you? when some answer solves your problem, please upvote and accept that answer. It's a nice move and it will help others to identify accepted answer.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Yes of course, I've already done it.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple:

1. *if* block (*your list is empty*): Node just gets added as the first and only element, hence it's the *top* and it's the *last*;
2. *else* block (*your list is not empty*): You iterate over the nodes, namely you move to the *next* node, again, and again, until you reach the last (tail) one, and the moment you reach it - you add the received argument(node) as the *next* node of the currently last one.

I hope this helps.

Comment: pointer node is referencing to the top node. For that reason it is then added to the top node?    Thanks for the help

Comment: @AgustinSamper pay attention, that your *pointer* is reassigned on every next iteration, with the node returned by `.getNext()`, and this happens until you reach the end of the list, until you fetch the currently *last* element of your list.

Comment: Ahh I got it!, the memory addres of the new node is assigned to the next position of the last node. Thank you so much!. I didn't understand how was it kept.

Comment: @AgustinSamper whenever you want to thank someone here, better to upvote and accept the answer, that's how it works here. You're welcome.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I think he actually might be too new to accept an answer?

Answer (score 1):

1. Assume your node is Empty i.e. the code goes in the IF block and the **aux** node gets attached to the top node.
2. Now if the node is not empty then it goes in the else block where it makes a new Pointer initialized with the top node. The while loop iterates till it finds a pointer which has null value. And finally attaches the new aux node at the end pf the node.
   To get proper visual idea you may watch youtube channels like mycodeschool.

Answer (score 0):

Great answers but I found this explanation slightly clearer:

1. You create an "aux" Node and pass the argument "element" to the Node constructor.
2. If your list is empty, there's no other nodes, so you simply set "top" as the node "aux" (the Node you've just created).
3. Else, you create a pointer pointing to the "top" node and loop until it doesn't have a reference to the *next* element. When you reach that point (aka *the last element*, where you have no next), you set it's next node to "aux", making aux the last node.